Getting a segmentation fault when initializing a pointer of a base class with a pointer of a derived class
When I initialize a pointer by direct passing the object (&circle) it works. When creating a pointer (circle_ref(&circle)) and passing circle_ref to the constructor I get a segmentation fault.
Here is the code:
CircleTarget::CircleTarget(float radius, sf::Texture& texture, sf::Vector2f pos)
        : circle(radius)
        , circle_ref(&circle)
        , Entity(pos, circle_ref) // Initialize the base class Entity with reference to circle
        , hitbox(this)
    {}

vs:
CircleTarget::CircleTarget(float radius, sf::Texture& texture, sf::Vector2f pos)
        : circle(radius)
        , circle_ref(&circle)
        , Entity(pos, &circle) // Initialize the base class Entity direct passing circle
        , hitbox(this)
    {}

I'm curious what's going on here. Note the signature of Entity constructor expects a pointer to the base class of circle: sf::Shape*

Initializer list is not necessarily executed in the order that you write it. In particular here, Entity constructor must be called before any of the CircleTarget members are initialized. So you have undefined behavior because the value of circle_ref is likely indeterminate (assuming you did not use member initialization in the class definition). It's quite poor style to have your base class initializer appear after your member initializers. And in fact, some compilers will warn about this (and even the order of member initialization if different from order of definition).

The initializer list is executed in the order that members are declared in the class. Base classes are always initialized before data members

see What is the order of evaluation in a member initializer list?
